# Custom Ruby Routes in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Okay, these two related questions are in reference to [Railscast #21](http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication):

I'm having some trouble with routes.  Two issues:

1) The routes in the tutorial seem to be relative to the root of the application; I want them to be relative to the root of the model. So

"`http://example.com/login`" I need to be "`http://example.com/model/login`"  (and vice versa for logout).

I'm using permalinks to refer to my records, and I don't know how to specify an override, because every time I try to use "`http://example.com/model/login`" I get an error that says it can't find the *record* "login".  How can I override this for login/logout?

2) Going to a custom route for me doesn't seem to keep the custom route in my address bar.  So going to "`http://example.com/login`" gets me to the right page, but the browser now says "`http://example.com/session/new`" in the address bar.  In the tutorial this doesn't happen: the app serves the correct page and keeps the custom route in the address bar.  How can I get this to happen for me?

```
## Sessions Controller
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def create
    session[:password] = params[:password]
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully Logged In"
    redirect_to :controller => 'brokers', :action => 'index'
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully Logged Out"
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end

## Routes
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :brokers, :session
  map.login 'login', :controller => 'session', :action => 'create'
  map.logout 'logout', :controller => 'session', :action => 'destroy'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "root of the model"? You should make routes to *controllers* and their *actions*. The controller should communicate with the *model*.

The error messages can be a bit confusing, but as far as I can see, this url:

`http://example.com/model/login`

would call the action called *login* in the controller called *model* with an empty id (wich probably doesn't exist), using this route:

`map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'`

If you want to have a "subfolder" in your route you can use namespaces, I don't remember every detail about it but you can find a lot of info about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing_outside_in.html#_controller_namespaces_and_routing). A word of warning: namespaces makes the route debugging a lot harder, I've had a *lot* of fun figuring out wich route is really used. I ended up creating many very specific routes to be sure the correct one was used.